# How do I find all of the cracks in acrylic shower stall?

Tags: repair, shower

[image]

Serious illness in family, so I need to delay full remodel. Here is a pic of my 33 yr old shower stall.I think its acrylic.

1. I believe there is a crack near the drain.
2. the stain on the ceiling below aligns to the edge at the top of the pic.
3. So my plan is to replace the calk.
4. But what to do about the floor.  How do I find all the cracks?  Feel free to blow up the pic and annotate.  Or, can I bypass the problem by sealing the entire floor with a product (if one exists)?
   Your thoughts?

Comment: That leak could be anywhere in the shower but typically they'll occur where the shower surfaces meet (where the walls meet or the tile meets the shower pan). Your going to want to replace some of the drywall in the ceiling below the shower anyway so you might want to cut out a small section which might give you a better idea of the problem. However, I would remove all of the caulk/grout in the corners and along the top of the pan and recaulk it. Make sure it's clean and dry before applying the caulk. If the leak is at the drain you'll best be able to determine that from below.

Comment: the picture is not clear enough to show any cracks